# Uploading lists with bulkupload in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In my data model, one of my properties is a list.  How do I tell the bulk loader to convert the string into a list delimited by ' ' (space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- property: districts
  external_name: DISTRICTS
  # Type: String Stats: 6000 properties of this type in this kind.
  import_transform: "lambda x: x.split(' ')"
  export_transform: "' '.join"
```